# Can I remove my step response overshoot?

Tags: transfer-function, pid-controller, matlab, step-response

I am working on a balance controller for a robot. I found the open loop transfer function between the motor voltage and robot pitch angle:

```
G1 =
  
                    -589300 s^4 - 7.71e08 s^3 - 1.435e11 s^2 - 2.566e12 s - 7.683e09
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   s^7 + 2418 s^6 + 1.317e06 s^5 + 1.977e08 s^4 + 1.312e10 s^3 + 1.796e11 s^2 - 9.658e11 s - 1.525e13
```

The system has the open loop bode plot and nyquist plot:-

[image]

This system has one RHP pole and no RHP zeroes, so it is an unstable system (beucase there are no encirclements of -1). To fix stability while also enhancing the performance I added the following terms to my balance controller.

1. A negative proportional gain: \$K_p = -1 \$
2. A post integrator: \$G_{ip} = \frac{0.05s + 1}{0.05s} \$
3. An integrator: \$ G_i\frac{0.5s + 1}{0.5s}\$
4. A lead term in the forward branch: \$G_d = \frac{0.06086s + 1}{0.01826s + 1} \$

After adding these to my controller, the entire system is now stable. I plotted the step response with the following code (there is unity feedback):

```
Gcl = feedback(G1*Kp*Gip*Gi*Gd,1)
```

[image]

The step response has a fast rise time, but about 50% overshoot. The settling time is also fine and there is no oscillations, so I am just looking for a way to remove that overshoot, even if it means a slower system. Is there a way to do that?

### Edit

Playing and reducing the gains gives me these step responses:-

[image]

Here is the root locus plot of the original open loop system without my terms:-

[image]

### Edit 2

I added a lowpass filter like Andy suggested, and I hope I did it right, by first finding the closed loop transfer function (there is unity feedback): \$G_{cl}=\frac{G_{ol} \cdot G_{low}}{1+G_{ol}} \$ and it gives me these step responses for different lowpass filters:-

[image]

Comment: reduce your gains

Comment: @JonRB You mean reduce \$K_p \$ to like -0.5 for example?

Comment: How long does it take you to alter one variable and check the result?

Comment: @JonRB I tried to reduce \$K_p \$ to \$K_p = -0.5\$ but that made the overshoot worse and added some slight oscillations.

Comment: you can't just blindly change the gains, they need to be "tuned"

Comment: OK, instead of altering anything, what if you forcibly slowed down the input step change with a low pass filter (outside the loop)? Try it. Mess with it and understand it.

Comment: @Andyaka Okay, I can try that. Just to be sure, when you say outside the loop do you mean outside the **open loop** such that the filter won't be included in the open loop transfer function?

Comment: @Andyaka Input shaping ?

Comment: @Carl Correct. Nobody's saying you can't screw around with the rise time of a demand signal are they?

Comment: @AJN correct. If it don't fit, make it fit.

Comment: Carl can you add the root locus of the open loop system, I think there doesn't exist and value of gain for the given controller where the poles are far from the imaginary axis. What ever way you tune the gain, some pole or other seem to go near the imaginary axis which can contribute to the over shoot. You may have to tune the controller ploes and zeros also.

Comment: @AJN I can add the root locus plot. Just to be sure again, you need a root locus plot of the original system without the various gains and terms I have added to my controller, right?

Comment: yes. root locus of `plant * Gip * Gi * Gd * Kp`. zoom in to show region bounded by +-100 on both axis as well as +-10 also. see if any gain values exist where all poles are to the left of a line described by `y=-x; for x<0`. if not, a low overshoot solution probably doesn't exist for this combination of controller poles and zeros. tune the zeros of the controller to see if the root locus will take all poles to the left of the above mentioned line for a single gain value. It is difficult to give a ready made solution for such a problem (IMHO).

Comment: @Andyaka I edited the question and added the step responses after I added a lowpass filter to the system. And it seems the overshoots for 1/(s+1) and 1/(0.5s+1) actually disappear!

Comment: [root locus](https://imgur.com/a/R4o5VQQ) that i plotted

Comment: Somewhere between s and 0.5s looks about right then.

Answer (score 3):

In a series controlled motor arm, the mechanical inertia and hysteresis and high slew rates, it is normal to have overshoot. Damping the input with a LPF blocks the spectrum that results in the overshoot but also reduces phase margin in the feedback loop. Putting the LPF after the loop may be impractical with a shock absorber to the arm or loading the output mechanically both reduce the overshoot.

Reducing the Kp gain  will reduce the slew rate and thus the spectral content that produced the overshoot,BW -3 dB = 0.35/Tr (10 to 90%) but also reduce the phase margin in the loop.

In human arms and legs all muscles are bipolar opposing forces that contract and relax to control force and position.  If you can modelled your design on this , then the hysteresis would drop and stability would be far better with opposing motors keeping the minimum tension for control, stability and rigidity from interference.

The problem logically is the stored energy to accelerate is not scaled to the load which might vary so the step response will change unless you change your maximum acceleration/torque current and use a profile that ramps up then predicts when to deaccelerate with zero overshoot in the fastest possible time.  This is how arms work in magnetic hard disk drives (HDD). So there are 3 controls for a,v,x with multiple feedbacks for current, servo velocity and position error.  **This is how I think you ought to control your system, not by analyzing the step response. K**eep in mind thermal effects on motor torque and load variations that dampen the response as well as hysteresis.

Comment: I appreciate the answer Tony, but I think it's way beyond the scope of what we are trying to do. Perhaps when I have a lot more experience I will fully understand your answer. But at this point my problem was solved by adding a prefilter in the form of a lowpass filter.

Comment: It’s not complicated, , make current your acceleration and velocity ramps up to max then negative current deacceleration ramp Down in velocity and then close the loop on a velocity ramp down just before going into position error tracking. With a simple algorithm based on the mass being moved and f=ma = current then x time = distance to brake before going into Position tracking , it works well every time a= /———\  then Position tracking at the right moment for the last little bit. Otherwise your filter will over damp small moves and underdamped large moves with more mass.

Comment: I assume you have current feedback and position feedback right? So you can compute velocity. step response is not the best test, but a whole range of seeks with different directions , mass and path length.